# Return value from Rust backend in Tauri causing Unhandled Promise Rejection in Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

I'm implementing a clone of 2048 using Tauri with Rust on the backend and Javascript on the frontend. Currently, I am passing the board from the frontend along with the user's move to the backend where the Rust code will process the board and user input before returning the board to the front end to be displayed to the user.

The board is represented as a two dimensional array of integers in Javascript. The state is held in the front end, so I am setting the board to be whatever is returned from the Rust code after each call to the backend. The callback works for the first iteration, but on subsequent iterations, the Javascript throws the following error:

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: invalid args board for command player_move: invalid type: map, expected an array of length 4`

This is the Javascript I am using.

```
function player_move() {
  board = invoke("player_move", { input: moveInputEl.value, board: board});
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  moveInputEl = document.querySelector("#player-move-input");
  document.querySelector("#player-move-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    player_move();
  });
});
```

And here is the Rust function on the back end:

```
#[tauri::command]
fn player_move(input: &str, mut board: [[i32; BOARD_SIZE]; BOARD_SIZE]) -> [[i32; BOARD_SIZE]; BOARD_SIZE] {
    let dir: Direction = get_direction(input);
    println!("{:#?}", dir);

    let mut score = 0;

    match dir{
        Direction::Up =>
            for i in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                for j in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                    shift_board(&mut board, &dir, [i, j], &mut score);
                }
            }
        Direction::Down =>
            for i in (0..BOARD_SIZE).rev(){
                for j in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                    shift_board(&mut board, &dir, [i, j], &mut score);
                }
            }
        Direction::Left =>
            for i in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                for j in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                    shift_board(&mut board, &dir, [i, j], &mut score);
                }
            }
        Direction::Right =>
            for i in 0..BOARD_SIZE{
                for j in (0..BOARD_SIZE).rev(){
                    shift_board(&mut board, &dir, [i, j], &mut score);
                }
            }
        Direction::None => println!("invalid player move")
    }

    add_number(&mut board);
}
```

Presumably there is some issue with how I am returning the array that represents the board, but my google searches so far have proved fruitless.

Comment: Did you check what do you get in the Network tab of the developer tools as a response from backend?

Comment: `invoke()` returns a `Promise`, so you'll need to `await` the result.

Comment: I just looked in the Network tab, and I just see 0 B transferred in either direction. I'm  definitely getting the data in the backend though, so I may be looking at the wrong thing

Comment: @kmdreko that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invoke()` returns a `Promise`, so you'll need to `await` the result. Otherwise you are trying to pass a `Promise` instead of an array on the next invocation.